# JavaScript - Encode/Decode UTF8 to Hex and Hex to UTF8

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, hex

In my Client/Server application I'm getting from the server, string in Hex format which I need to convert to UTF8. Then after some manipulation I need to encode the string back, from UTF8 to Hex and return in to the server.

I've built this function to parse the Hex string to UTF8. However when I try to reverse this algorithm I'm getting something completely else.

Here is my test:

```js
function hexToUtf8(s)
{
  return decodeURIComponent(
     s.replace(/\s+/g, '') // remove spaces
      .replace(/[0-9a-f]{2}/g, '%$&') // add '%' before each 2 characters
  );
}

function utf8ToHex(s)
{
  return encodeURIComponent(s).replace(/%/g, ""); // remove all '%' characters
}

var hex = "52656c6179204f4e214f706572617465642062792030353232";

var utf8 = hexToUtf8(hex); // result: "Relay ON!Operated by 0522" (correct value)
var hex2 = utf8ToHex(utf8); // result: "Relay20ON!Operated20by200522" (some junk)

console.log("Hex: " + hex);
console.log("UTF8: " + utf8);
console.log("Hex2: " + hex2);
console.log("Is conversion OK: " + (hex == hex2)); // false
```

Comment: I made you a snippet to have a [mcve]

Comment: You seem to forget the spaces in hex2

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` is not HEX, are you sure it's HEX your after?

Comment: @Keith - I'm **sure** I want to get the result in Hex, I **don't sure** I need to use `encodeURIComponent`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your utf8toHex is using encodeURIComponent, and this won't make everything HEX.

So I've slightly modified your utf8toHex to handle HEX.

> Update
> Forgot toString(16) does not pre-zero the hex, so if they was
> values less 16, eg. line feeds etc it would fail
> So, to added the 0 and sliced to make sure.
>
> Update 2,
> Use TextEncoder, this will handle UTF-8 much better than use charCodeAt.

```js
function hexToUtf8(s)
{
  return decodeURIComponent(
     s.replace(/\s+/g, '') // remove spaces
      .replace(/[0-9a-f]{2}/g, '%$&') // add '%' before each 2 characters
  );
}

const utf8encoder = new TextEncoder();

function utf8ToHex(s)
{
  const rb = utf8encoder.encode(s);
  let r = '';
  for (const b of rb) {
    r += ('0' + b.toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }
  return r;
}


var hex = "d7a452656c6179204f4e214f706572617465642062792030353232";

var utf8 = hexToUtf8(hex);
var hex2 = utf8ToHex(utf8);

console.log("Hex: " + hex);
console.log("UTF8: " + utf8);
console.log("Hex2: " + hex2);
console.log("Is conversion OK: " + (hex == hex2));
```

Comment: After implement this code in my app, I found out that it will **not work**. The problem appear in foreign languages, where the function `charCodeAt()` returns a value with 3 characters or more. For example if `hex  = 'd7a4'` will be equal to 'פ' in UTF. then back to Hex you'll get `5e4` which **isn't** equal to `d7a4`

Comment: This happen because `charCodeAt()` return the value in UTF-16 not UTF-8. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt

Comment: @GilEpshtain  Yes, UTF8 double width chars will be an issue, I'll see if I can knock something up a little bit more robust here.

Comment: @GilEpshtain  Update to use TextEncoder, as that really should be the proper way to handle UTF8, you could also use the TextDecoder but using decodeURIComponent to act as a simple HEX decoder seems fine.